# JDBCAppended not working

Tags: oracle, log4j

I am trying to use `JDBCAppender` for logging `log4j` messages. But log is not getting published in DB though there aren't any exceptions. How do I trace down the problem? Here is an example `log4j` entry:

```
`<appender name="db" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@rsasitdb.corp.unifirst.com:1522:rsasit"/>
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="user" value="rsa"/>
        <param name="password" value="rsa"/>
        <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d','%C','%p','%m')"/> 
        <!-- <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="INSERT INTO LOGGING_SAMPLES_TEST (log_date, log_level, location, message) VALUES ( '%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C;%L', '%m' )" 
            /> 
        </layout> -->
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"></layout>
    </appender>
------------------
<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="db"/>
    </logger>`
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a LOGS table in your database, and that your "rsa" user has INSERT access to it. Can you show us what its table structure looks like? Column types, etc.

Comment: yes,it has.How can i debug?CREATE TABLE LOGS
   (USER_ID VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
    DATED   DATE            NOT NULL,
    LOGGER  VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
    LOG_LEVEL   VARCHAR2(10)    NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE VARCHAR2(1000)  NOT NULL
   )